# How i can read memory address fetched using pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, memory-address

I want to know what is this **(0x6dfe80)** memory address? and how it can be useful in coding. And if i fetched a memory address and how i can read it and estimate where is this memory location.

- what is meant by 0x?
- what is meant by 6d?
- what is meant by fe?
- what is meant by 80?

or how this memory location is arranged?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int a,b,c;
    int* pointer_a; int* pointer_b; int* pointer_c;


    pointer_a = &a;
    pointer_b = &b;
    pointer_c = &c;

    cout<<"Address of variable a : "<<pointer_a<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of variable b : "<<pointer_b<<endl;
    cout<<"Address of variable c : "<<pointer_c<<endl;

    return (0);
}
```

[image: Code]

Comment: [Hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) system on wikipedia

Comment: It's so-called [hexadecimal notation](https://wiki.osdev.org/Hexadecimal_Notation).

Comment: Printing the value of a pointer (where the pointer is pointing) is mostly useless, especially on a modern system with virtual memory. As for why pointers might be needed that's way to broad a question really.

Comment: Fun fact: if you didn't take an address of `a`, `b`, `c`, there wouldn't be any as they would probably be in registers.

Comment: And hexadecimal notation should be part of any decent book, class or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is meant by 0x?

0x is a prefix that signifies a number in hexadecimal (which means 16) base (also called radix). Addresses are conventionally serialised in hexadecimal.

> what is meant by 6d?
>   what is meant by fe?
>   what is meant by 80?

These are hexadecimal digits. It is a number.

> and how it can be useful in coding.

Indirection has many uses. For example, it can be used to implement a tree data structure.